# Spring EL: Safe navigation with map access

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm using Spring EL to pull values out of a rather complex set of nested maps and lists. I want to be able to use an expression like

```
[9]['firstSubKey']['secondSubKey']
```

except that `[9]['firstSubKey']` might be null. I can't figure out how to use the safe navigation correctly: I tried

```
[9]['firstSubKey']?['secondSubKey']
```

and

```
[9]['firstSubKey']?.['secondSubKey']
```

and both returned some kind of parse error. I eventually got it to work by using

```
[9]['firstSubKey']?.get('secondSubKey')
```

but that feels tacky. Is there a better way or is this just a feature SpringEL doesn't have? I'm using Spring 3.1.3.

Relatedly, if I have a list/array of an unknown number of elements, is there a way to check for that safely? IE if I have an array of 4 elements, I want `[5]` to return null. As is, it throws a `SpelEvaluationException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't come up with a better solution to yours; only

`"['0']['a'] != null ? ['0']['a']['b'] : null"`

and

`"size() > 5 ? [5] : null"`